# dates interval bigger then it should be

Tags: java

I have: startDate = 24.03.2013 21:01:20  endDate = 24.03.2013 21:01:40

I do in my code

```
Date d = new Date(endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime)
```

and d = 01.01.1970 02:00:20

Where it takes 2 hours, the interval should be 20 seconds, but I get 2 hours and 20 seconds.
Why it happens? What to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is `new Date("difference between two dates")` and getting a time in 
01.01.1970.  But what timezone-offset was in effect on 01.01.1970 at your locale? I'm guessing +02 hours.

You should also print the result of `new Date(0L)` and compare the difference.  Or ensure the timezone is set to UTC when you display the date.

Comment: I change my code to:  Date tz = new Date(2L);
     final long hoursInMillis = 60L * 60L * 1000L;
     Date d = new Date(end.getTime()-start.getTime()-tz.getHours()*hoursInMillis);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did there but I get correct result:

http://ideone.com/dTbugh

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date startDate = df.parse("24.03.2013 21:01:20");
    Date endDate = df.parse("24.03.2013 21:01:40");
    Date d = new Date(endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime());
    System.out.print(d);
```

output:
Thu Jan 01 00:00:20 GMT 1970